# Getting corefrences with Standard corenlp package

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to get coreferences in a text. I'm new to the corenlp package. I tried the code below, which doesn't work, but I'm open to other methods as well.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package corenlp;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.CorefGraphAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.NamedEntityTagAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.semgraph.SemanticGraph;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.IntTuple;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.Pair;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.Timing;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import java.util.Properties;
/**
 *
 * @author Karthi
 */
public class Main {


        // creates a StanfordCoreNLP object, with POS tagging, lemmatization, NER, parsing, and coreference resolution
    Properties props = new Properties();
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("Main.properties");

    props.load(in);
    in.close();
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    // read some text in the text variable
    String text = "The doctor can consult with other doctors about this patient. If that is the case, the name of the doctor and the names of the consultants have to be maintained. Otherwise, only the name of the doctor is kept. "; // Add your text here!

    // create an empty Annotation just with the given text
    Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

    // run all Annotators on this text
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    System.out.println(document);
    // these are all the sentences in this document
    // a CoreMap is essentially a Map that uses class objects as keys and has values with custom types
    List<CoreMap> sentences = (List<CoreMap>) document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
    System.out.println(sentences);
    for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
      // traversing the words in the current sentence
      // a CoreLabel is a CoreMap with additional token-specific methods
      for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
        // this is the text of the token
        String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);
        // this is the POS tag of the token
        String pos = token.get(PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
        // this is the NER label of the token
        String ne = token.get(NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);
      }

      // this is the parse tree of the current sentence
      Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeAnnotation.class);
System.out.println(tree);
      // this is the Stanford dependency graph of the current sentence
      SemanticGraph dependencies = sentence.get(CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);
      System.out.println(dependencies);
    }

    // this is the coreference link graph
    // each link stores an arc in the graph; the first element in the Pair is the source, the second is the target
    // each node is stored as <sentence id, token id>. Both offsets start at 1!
    List<Pair<IntTuple, IntTuple>> graph = document.get(CorefGraphAnnotation.class);
    System.out.println(graph);

    }

}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Loading POS Model [// For POS model] ... Loading default properties from trained tagger // For POS model
Error: No such trained tagger config file found.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\ For POS model (The specified path is invalid)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TaggerConfig.getTaggerDataInputStream(TaggerConfig.java:741)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TaggerConfig.<init>(TaggerConfig.java:178)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:228)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.loadModel(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:57)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.<init>(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:44)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:441)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:434)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:62)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:309)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:347)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:337)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:329)
        at corenlp.Main.main(Main.java:66)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\ For POS model (The specified path is invalid)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:443)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:434)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:62)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:309)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:347)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:337)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:329)
        at corenlp.Main.main(Main.java:66)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\ For POS model (The specified path is invalid)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TaggerConfig.getTaggerDataInputStream(TaggerConfig.java:741)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:643)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:268)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:228)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.loadModel(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:57)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.<init>(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:44)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:441)
        ... 7 more
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: check if Main.properties file in the accessible path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error simply means the program is not finding the data models it needs to run.  They need to be on your classpath.  If you're in the distribution directory, you can do this with a command like:

```
java -cp stanford-corenlp-2010-11-12.jar:stanford-corenlp-models-2010-11-06.jar:xom.jar:jgrapht.jar -Xmx3g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref -file input.txt
```

The second jar contains the models. If you're using Windows, replace the colons above with semicolons.

Comment: What if i'm using it in a web application processing some strings?
I have included Jar's in my build, still i'm getting this exact error!!

Comment: You need. That models jar in your CLASSPATH at runtime.

Comment: @ChristopherManning What is the use of xom.jar??

Comment: xom is for XML output. It's a java DOM library. If you don't want XML output, you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

I did the follows:

- use the imports Tex provided as above
- check if Main.properties file in the accessible path. as karthi said.
- replace 
  `<List<Pair<IntTuple, IntTuple>> graph = document.get(CorefGraphAnnotation.class);` 
  with `Map<Integer, CorefChain> graph = document.get(CorefChainAnnotation.class);`
- I got the results as follows. Is it enough?

> {1=CHAIN1-["The doctor" in sentence 1, "the doctor" in sentence 2,
>   "the doctor"  in sentence 3], 2=CHAIN2-["other doctors about this
>   patient" in sentence 1], 4=C HAIN4-["this patient" in sentence 1],
>   5=CHAIN5-["that" in sentence 2, "the case" in sentence 2],
>   7=CHAIN7-["the name of the doctor and the names of the consultants" in
>   sentence 2, "only the name of the doctor" in sentence 3],
>   9=CHAIN9-["the doctor and the names of the consultants" in sentence
>   2], 11=CHAIN11-["the names of the consultants" in sentence 2],
>   13=CHAIN13-["the consultants" in sentence 2 ]}

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the files' structure has changed slightly since the version in both this topic and in the snippet here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml

Replace the imports with those:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.semgraph.SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefGraphAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.semgraph.SemanticGraph;
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefChain
```

That did the trick for me ;-)